# GPU does not work on the distributed tensorflow cluster

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, distributed

I am testing distributed tensorflow using the official code, I have two servers with one K80 GPU and one M40 GPU on them, but running the code on the clusters, only the worker that is specified "is_chief=True" can use the GPU to compute, and the other one is just using CPU, even I have specified the GPU device on it. Part of my code is like below:

```
def main(_):
worker_hosts = ['ipaddress0:2222', 'ipaddress1:2222']
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"worker": worker_hosts})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name='worker', task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    mnist=input_data.read_data_sets('data', one_hot=True)
    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d/gpu:0" % (FLAGS.task_index), cluster=cluster)):
        print('building model...')
        global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
        train_step, cross_entropy, accuracy, y, x, y_, keep_prob=build_model(global_step)
        init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

    hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=1000000)]
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target, 
        is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0), 
        checkpoint_dir="/tmp/train_logs", 
        hooks=hooks,
        ) as mon_sess:
        mon_sess.run(init)
        i=0
        while not mon_sess.should_stop() and i<=20000:
            i+=1
            batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
            if i%50 == 0:
                train_accuracy= mon_sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
                print ("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(mon_sess.run(global_step), train_accuracy))
            mon_sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
        print ("test accuracy %g"%mon_sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

And the server of ipaddress0 with task_index 0 can use the K80 GPU to compute, the other is using CPU. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? Please offer some help, THANKS

Comment: It appears from your deleted answer that you have solved the problem. Is that correct? (And if so, how did you solve it?)

Comment: It's just a very simple question, I just change the name of worker_device from "/job:worker/task:0" to "/job:worker/replica:0/task:0" and both gpu worked. The official code may have a small mistake...@mrry

Comment: As far as I understand, adding `/replica:0` to a device name shouldn't have any effect, because all devices are implicitly in the 0th replica (that part of the device name is a legacy feature that isn't used). If there's a particular tutorial in which you think there's an error though, please provide a link and we'll check it out!

Comment: I don't really understand the inner mechanism of Tensorflow, but according to my practical test, the sub-worker(not specified 'ischief=True') will only use cpu if not explicitly adding '/replica:0'. Or have you ever met the related problem? Maybe you and your team can do some comprehensive tests to give us a more official plan to solve this problem. Thanks! @mrry